# Where to find Page of Blacksmithing?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Farming Pages/Tomes of Crafting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66788/farming-pages-tomes-of-crafting)

Where can I find Pages of Blacksmithing?
I need them to upgrade my blacksmith to the next level.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this question about any game in particular?